Webpack over CDN import to vue js The requested module 'url' does not provide an export named 'default'
Hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on a JavaScript module that I plan to load via a Content Delivery Network (CDN) using the URL https://x.com/my-script.js. However, I've hit a snag despite trying various webpack configurations.
Environment :

VueJS 3.3.4
Webpack 5.88.1
Webpack-cli 5.1.4

To clarify, when I simplify my module without webpack, like so:
const randomGenerator = {
    generateRandomNumber: function(min, max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() \* (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
};

export default randomGenerator;

...the import works like a charm. Here's how I import and use the module:
import  randomGenerator from 'https://x.com/my-script.js'; 

console.log(randomGenerator.generateRandomNumber(1, 100));


Responses in the following Stack Question  tels you how to export default and import named-default-javascript
But when I throw webpack into the mix, I get this error:
requested module 'https://x.com/my-script.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
I suspected it's a webpack configuration issue, so I consulted the Webpack documentation, which recommends configuring output like so  for a Universal Module Definition which are capable of working everywhere, be it in the client, on the server or elsewhere as noted in github :
 output: {  
   filename: 'compactedModule.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  
   library:'randomGenerator',
   libraryTarget: 'umd'  
 }

I also checked out how Axios axios.min.js  is built, and it's similar
Finally here is my full webpack config file :
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: '../src/test.js',
  output: {  
       filename: 'compactedModule.js',
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  
       library:'randomGenerator',
       libraryTarget: 'umd'  
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};

Note that for every changement I make to the bundle module I clear browser cache
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Solved by adding the script tag in the index.html file
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.com/my-script.js" defer></script>

And then for usage inside the component you can call the function as follow
window.randomGenerator.generateRandomNumber

but note that the script will be loaded in each page load I will post another answer once I find out how to load only in a specific page inside one vuejs component
